# How to find the logs on Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio

I have tried to import my project to Android Studio and I got this error. I need to know where I can get the logs.

```
Consult IDE log for more details (Help | Show Log)
```

Comment: Did you try View > Tool Windows > Android?

Comment: There is an option in your Toolbar to check your logs by enabling (DDMS i.e. android icon) or else in bottom you can check Android>>Devices | logcat.

Comment: @PankajKumar I want to know where to find logs.how this question will be duplicate?

Comment: @Gru it doesnot show anything about y this project has not been integrated?

Comment: @AravindAsthme have you imported eclipse project in android studio????.

Comment: @Gru it does not let me to import.i don't know y.so i thought log will be helpful

Comment: @fasteque i have tried.it does not show any thing

Comment: there is a way find Alias, keystore password and key password. I just recovered and saved myself from a lot of trouble. Please refer this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28034899/how-to-retrieve-key-alias-and-key-password-for-signed-apk-in-android-studiomigr

Comment: In my Windows 10 "Help/Show Log In Explorer" goes to "This Computer" view and it does not go to the directory where the logs are. The logs can be found manually in C:\Users\<yourid>\.AndroidStudioPreview\system\log

Answer (score 239, accepted):

On toolbar -> `Help Menu` -> `Show log in Explorer` or `Show log in Finder` (for Mac users).

It opens log folder, where you can find all logs.

[image]

Comment: @Alston is it a good reason to downvote an answer of 3 years ago? In 2.2.3 the Help is in the same position. Check the toolbar, last entry on the right "Help" then "show log in explorer".

Comment: For mac users, that would be `Show Log in Finder`

Comment: I got the same error, however the log shows no valuable information yet: 2021-12-07 14:32:10,627 [ 156388]  ERROR - intellij.openapi.progress.Task - OS: Linux 
2021-12-07 14:32:10,628 [ 156389]  ERROR - intellij.openapi.progress.Task - Last Action:  
2021-12-07 14:32:10,722 [ 156483]   INFO - cState$SyncStateUpdaterService - stopTrackingTask(RESOLVE_PROJECT:0) 
2021-12-07 14:32:10,726 [ 156487]   WARN - e.project.sync.GradleSyncState - Gradle sync failed: Sync failed: reason unknown (55 s 334 ms)

Comment: It works only if you have some project opened (at least it's true for my Android Studio Chipmunk | 2021.2.1 Patch 2), so you have to open some project or create at least blank project first

Answer (score 28):

On a Mac, the idea.log is contained in

```
/Users/<user>/Library/Logs/AndroidStudio/idea.log
```

The new stable version (1.2) is in

```
/Users/<user>/Library/Logs/AndroidStudio1.2/
```

The new stable version (2.2) is in

```
/Users/<user>/Library/Logs/AndroidStudio2.2/
```

The new stable version (3.4) is in

```
/Users/<user>/Library/Logs/AndroidStudio3.4/
```

(From auspicious99 comment)
On **MacOS Catalina** and **Big Sur** (at least), Android Studio 4.1, the `idea.log` can be found in,

```
/Users/<user>/Library/Logs/Google/AndroidStudio4.1/
```

Comment: can't find AndroidStudio in ~/Library

Comment: See the full path above (AndroidStudio is in the Logs subdirectory of Library), and remember, this is for the Mac on OSX.

Comment: On MacOS Catalina and Big Sur (at least), Android Studio 4.1, the idea.log can be found in /Users/<user>/Library/Logs/Google/AndroidStudio4.1/

Comment: On Monterey (12.5) I found it at ~/Library/Logs/Google/AndroidStudio2021.2

Answer (score 15):

I had the same problem and after some searching I was able to find my logs at the following location:

`C:\Users\<yourid>\.AndroidStudioPreview\system\log`

Answer (score 12):

Just because none of these pointed to the correct location on my Win10 system

C:\Users[*User Name*]\AppData\Local\Google\AndroidStudio4.2\log\idea.log

Answer (score 11):

My Android Studio is 3.0, please follow the two steps below,hope this will help;)
[image: First step.]
[image: Second step]

Answer (score 5):

**Android Studio find a log**

MacOS version

```
Help -> Show Log in Finder
```

In my case it is:

```
/Users/alex/Library/Logs/Google/AndroidStudio4.2/idea.log
```

Answer (score 3):

There is no way to get the logs for installing problems.

Answer (score 3):

Had a hard time finding the logs because the IDE was crashing on launch, if you are on **Mac** and use **Android Studio 4.1** then the logs location may be found at **/Users/{user}/Library/Logs/Google/AndroidStudio4.1/**

And to be specific for me it is on **macOS Big Sur**

Answer (score 2):

You could open **Messages** or **Event Log** tool window to see your log.
In addition to that if you want to see device log then you could open **Logcat** tool window to view your log : **View > Tool Windows > Logcat**
[image]

Comment: The question was not asking for event log or logcat, but for the IDE log. Event log is like a subset of the IDE log.

Answer (score 1):

Hope this helps someone: on Mac OS X, the logs are within `/Users/<user>/Library/Logs/AndroidStudio<version>/`

Comment: Thanks!
They moved it into a Google folder though. It's now in:
/Users/<user>/Library/Logs/Google/AndroidStudio<version>/

Answer (score 1):

The path to the log files in Windows has been moved.

They appear to be under `C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\caches\trunk-system\log\idea.log` in Android Studio 4.1.1

Answer (score 1):

If you got here because you can't start an emulator and Android Studio gives you that error message:

- kill **qemu-system-x86_64.exe** and **adb** processes

(Windows 10)

Answer (score 0):

In ubuntu it should be under

> /home/user_name/product_name/system/log

where 
user_name is logged in user name and
product_name could be e.g. .AndroidStudio1.5

Answer (score 0):

In windows version

you can find the log in the bottom of the IDE, click the "Gradle Console", and then choose the "Android Monitor". You will see a Droplistbox control which shows "Verbose" as a default value.

If you use `log.v()` . Verbose option is okay. if you use `log.d()`, just change it to Debug.

So when you run your emulator, you can catch your log from this window.

Answer (score 0):

C:\Users\bob.AndroidStudio2.3\system\log

Answer (score 0):

On my Ubuntu system it was under `~/.cache/Google/AndroidStudio2022.2/log/`.

Answer (score 0):

For me on Windows, it was at:

```
%LocalAppData%\Google\AndroidStudio2023.1\log\idea.log
```