# Android Studio: Gradle error

Tags: android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I have created a project in Android Studio but when I'm about to run it, this message appears:

> 'Unexpected exception while reading 9-patch file: Unable to parse
>   file:
>   F:/Lazarillo/app/build/intermediates/exploded-aar/com.android.support/appcompat-v7/22.2.0/res/drawable-hdpi/abc_btn_switch_to_on_mtrl_00012.9.png
>   '

I have tried to create new gradles but it's just impossible, it doesn't run anyway.

There are no errors in the code, everything looks flawless, what should I do?

Comment: What does your 9-patch file look like? Does it have the proper borders?

Comment: check your logs (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19784877/how-to-find-the-logs-on-android-studio) to obtain more info. Also check your 9-patch file. It may be broken for some reason. Try to recreate it.