# Android Studio is not accepting new project

Tags: android, android-studio

I want to start learning Android programming and recently downloaded the Android Studio. Now if I want to start a new project, I can't get past this initial screen. Whenever I click next, the window just jerks, which I guess is indicating that I am doing something wrong. So how can I solve this problem?

[image: Android Studio Project Wizard]

Note: I am a total beginner but I am genuinely trying to learn and searching the web for the problem didn't give me any solution.

Comment: don't you get an error message then?

Comment: Try resinstalling JAVA and Android Studio.

Comment: Nope. If I try to click next, it just shakes and only the previous and cancel button remains clickable. If I click the previous button it just takes me to the Application Name section and if I click cancel, it just exits Android Studio.

Comment: @PrerakSola I did. I even updated the java jdk and jre to update8_101 and reset all the path variables. Then uninstalled and installed Android studio in a new location. but nothing changed.

Comment: have checked if that project location already exists?

Answer (score 0):

I guess something is wrong with your Android Studio / JDK installation. In the status bar on the bottom, I can see a NullPointerException. I think this is the cause. Try to open the Android Studio Log and hopefully the error is better explained there.

[How to find Android Studio Log](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19784877/how-to-find-the-logs-on-android-studio)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have unknown characters in your package name like "ı,ö,ü" ? And you may want to watch a android starter tutorial video which has a part about starting a project to see if you are doing something wrong?

If it couldn't be a good answer sorry for it but that's all i can offer :3

Comment: Please use comments for vague statements.

Comment: Yeah in fact i agree but there is not a "add comment" button under the question i dont know why

Comment: @TahaSümer You can't comment because you need 50 reputation points do do so. Please see [Why do I need 50 reputation to comment? What can I do instead?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/214173/204841).