# Gradle sync failed Android studio 2.3.2

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

**Gradle sync failed: A problem occurred configuring project ':app'. Consult IDE log for more details.**

Hence I'm very new to the Android Studio just tried to setup for the first time.  Even I tried all the methods which mentioned for the gradle sync failed unfortunately nothing works. Please help to find the issue.

Classpath:

> buildscript {
>      repositories {
>          jcenter()
>      }
>      dependencies {
>          classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.2'
>
> ```
>    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they >belong
>    // in the individual module build.gradle files
> ```
>
> }
>   }

Wrapper Properties :

> ## Wed May 24 08:00:32 IST 2017
>
> distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
>   distributionPath=wrapper/dists
>   zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
>   zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
>   distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-3.3-all.zip

Error while Re-Building :

```
 Error:A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
 > java.lang.NullPointerException (no error message)
```

Thanks in advance

Update : Added Logs

[Logs](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1nEIFeimVDcSM79HBsl7sinlt6JsgHDiZrrDwv6myqQQ/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: On toolbar -> Help Menu -> Show log in explorer.

This link may help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19784877/how-to-find-the-logs-on-android-studio

Comment: user8118976, is it possible for you to share the error log ?

Comment: I have updated the post with logs. Please share your thoughts

Comment: @Sudhakar_ak have a solve?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error with an up-to-date Android Studio (4.1.3) and a recent NDK (22.0.7026061 downloaded via Studio).

First of all, even if your NDK was downloaded through Studio you can/must specify your NDK directory in your local.properties file :
ndk.dir=/path/to/ndk

But in my case, having a correct NDK path specified in local.properties wasn't enough, like for you Android Studio (gradle) kept refusing to build.
So I ended up manually creating an empty directory "platforms" in the NDK installation folder, then invalidated & restarted Studio. And surprisingly, it seems to resolve the thing.

Answer (score 0):

Try Build -> Clean Project andthen try it again

Comment: Tried, Still the same error persists. Build and rebuild doesn't give any effect. I can't see anything run after I click Build and Rebuild.

Answer (score 0):

Clean the project & try again. If that didn't help too, restart android studio.

Comment: Tried, Still the same error persists. Build and rebuild doesn't give any effect. I can't see anything run after I click Build and Rebuild.

Comment: Try restarting your system then.

Comment: Tried ..No luck

Answer (score 0):

Follow these three steps:

1. Check if your project level `build.gradle` file has this line:
   `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.2'`
2. Make sure your `gradle-wrapper.properties` file in `gradle` folder looks exactly like this:
3. Delete `.gradle` folder from your project directory
   `

   distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
   distributionPath=wrapper/dists
   zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
   zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
   distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-3.3-all.zip

`
 4. Build -> Clean Project
 5. File -> Invalidate Caches/Restart
 6. Build -> Rebuild Project

Comment: Tried, Still the same error persists. Build and rebuild doesn't give any effect. I can't see anything run after I click Build and Rebuild.

Comment: Updated the answer.

Comment: Classpath, gradle,wrapper properties are exactly same. Build >clean project is not taking any effect.