# KVM is required to run this AVD. Unknown Error! Please file a bug against Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, kvm

Operating System : CentOS Linux 7
Android Studios version : 2.3.3

Result of the command: `lsmod | grep kvm`

[image: lsmod | grep kvm]

My computer supports virtualization but when i try to start the emulator  I get this error:

[image: Android Studios Error]

```
2017-06-19 19:11:58,120 [  98282]   INFO - figurations.GeneralCommandLine - Cannot run program "/home/folder/Android/Sdk/emulator/emulator-check": error=13, Permission denied 
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "/home/folder/Android/Sdk/emulator/emulator-check": error=13, Permission denied
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1048)
    at com.intellij.execution.configurations.GeneralCommandLine.startProcess(GeneralCommandLine.java:368)
    ... more
2017-06-19 19:15:28,593 [ 308755]   INFO - figurations.GeneralCommandLine - Cannot run program "/home/folder/Android/Sdk/emulator/emulator": error=13, Permission denied 
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "/home/folder/Android/Sdk/emulator/emulator": error=13, Permission denied
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:728)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: error=13, Permission denied
    at java.lang.UNIXProcess.forkAndExec(Native Method)
    ... more
```

Comment: If you find the logs of the IDE, that would help

Comment: Where is it located?

Comment: In linux? `/var/log` maybe? Or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19784877/how-to-find-the-logs-on-android-studio

Comment: SOLVED By doing `chmod 777 emulator/ -R`

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Changed permissions in the /home/folder/Android/Sdk/emulator/ folder

`chmod 777 -R /home/folder/Android/Sdk/emulator/`

Comment: Permissioned denied to which user? 777 seems excessive

Comment: From android studios all users even root could not access most of the files in the Sdk folder. Instead of 777 which level is best, 555(r-x)?

Comment: Ubuntu 18 
    'sudo apt-get install qemu-kvm libvirt-bin ubuntu-vm-builder bridge-utils'

Comment: The only items you need to change are `chmod 775 ~/Android/Sdk/emulator/emulator* ~/Android/Sdk/emulator/qemu/linux-x86_64/qemu-system-*` If you try running the emulator from the command line `~/Android/Sdk/emulator -avd (your avd name)` you can easily see any errors (use -list-avds to find your avd name). Seems strange that the emulator files are not executable by default?

Answer (score 13):

I also had this problem, and was able to fix it by using:

```
sudo chmod 777 /dev/kvm
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case the error was because the user has not enough permission to `/dev/kvm`.
So the solution is giving permission,i.e.,

```
chmod 777 /dev/kvm
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to be part of the kvm group

Try this:

```
sudo adduser $USER kvm
```

Then relaunch android studio or unlog / relog user