# /dev/kvm permission denied android emulator

Tags: android, android-studio, ubuntu, android-emulator

hi i install android stdio on Ubuntu 18.0 then i try to start android emulator i got error

> /dev/kvm permission denied

i try some stackoverflow question but its not solve my problem those question links are

1.[Android Studio: /dev/kvm device permission denied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37300811/android-studio-dev-kvm-device-permission-denied)

2.[KVM is required to run this AVD. Unknown Error! Please file a bug against Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44635879/kvm-is-required-to-run-this-avd-unknown-error-please-file-a-bug-against-androi)

3.[Ubuntu 14 Android Studio 3 xrdp /dev/kvm permission denied](https://askubuntu.com/questions/985142/ubuntu-14-android-studio-3-xrdp-dev-kvm-permission-denied)

t tried all this but its not solve my problem and i give chmod 777 permission also

```
chmod 777 -R /home/halfix/Android/Sdk/emulator/
```

still i have /de/kvm permission divided

Comment: Checkout this answer. It worked for me. https://stackoverflow.com/a/45749003/9384511

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Android studio can't access `/dev/kvm` directory. To allow access run

```
sudo chmod 777 -R /dev/kvm
```

It will ask for your password. After that restart android studio.

Comment: this will remove all restrictions for /dev/kvm for all users on your machine.
I'd recommend [Jerin's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51693686/11359707).

Answer (score 25):

I followed these steps to make it work in **Ubuntu 18.04**

Step 1: Install qemu-kvm

```
sudo apt install qemu-kvm
```

Step 2:

Add user to kvm group using:

```
sudo adduser <username> kvm
```

Step 3:
If it still showing *permission denied*:

```
sudo chown <username> /dev/kvm
```

Comment: I would suggest informing that the user may need to logout and login again after the command  "sudo adduser <username> kvm"

Answer (score 6):

No need to give whole permission to the kvm. you can give owner access for the kvm is fine like as follow

```
sudo chown <username>:<username> /dev/kvm
```

Comment: but i login as root

Comment: please check the permission of kvm file 
`ls -;ah /dev/kvm ` and check the user is root or not

Answer (score 2):

This is a realistic error message related to permission but mine happened to be the same message when java was not installed and ran the app. Hope this will help if would be my case.

Answer (score 1):

**/dev/kvm** permission denied android studio
[Motherboard]Set VT(Virtualization Technology) in BIOS and install Virtual Machine
https://www.asus.com/in/support/FAQ/1045141/#A

[image]

Comment: This is the perfect answer got 
thank you @Yogesh Bangar

Answer (score 0):

Ut worked for me:

```
sudo apt install qemu-kvm
```

Re-start **terminal** and execute the following command:

```
sudo chmod 777 -R /dev/kvm
```