# Pop-Up Window-Continues to crash

Tags: android, popup

I am trying to make a `PopupWindow` to explain my app, however I am having a lot of difficulty for a seemingly simple thing. I tried various youtube videos and looked at almost all the similar posts on here about it, but I haven't had any luck yet. If someone can please point out my flaw, that'd be great.

My end goal is for the PopupWindow to appear with the on create method, but I included a Button to start it for now because all the tutorials included one.

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    //BUILDING THE POP UP WINDOW ON CLICK OF HELP BUTTON

    help=(Button)findViewById(R.id.help);
    help.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            layoutInflater=(LayoutInflater)getBaseContext().getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            View customView= layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_instructions, null);

            popUpWindow=new PopupWindow(
                    customView,
                    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
            );
            myButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    popUpWindow.dismiss();
                }
            });
        }
    });
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. If I need to include any more information, please do ask. I am new to android and this is my first big Application so keeping my hopes up.

Thanks
[The link to my log](https://1drv.ms/u/s!AuU8iPdfWb_dmWlmtY8f183teEgz%22my%20log%22)

```
07-30 23:32:07.062 9273-9273/my.myCompany.vinay.diversityformulaapplication E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                              Process: my.myCompany.vinay.diversityformulaapplication, PID: 9273
                                                                                              java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{my.myCompany.vinay.diversityformulaapplication/my.myCompany.vinay.diversityformulaapplication.EntryScreen}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Button.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference
                                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2947)
                                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3008)
                                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap14(ActivityThread.java)
                                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1650)
                                                                                                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                                                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6688)
                                                                                                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1468)
                                                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1358)
                                                                                               Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Button.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference
                                                                                                  at my.myCompany.vinay.diversityformulaapplication.EntryScreen.onCreate(EntryScreen.java:37)
                                                                                                  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6912)
                                                                                                  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1126)
                                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2900)
                                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3008) 
                                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap14(ActivityThread.java) 
                                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1650) 
                                                                                                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                                                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
                                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6688) 
                                                                                                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1468) 
                                                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1358)
```

Comment: where's your log file?

Comment: How do I get the log files?

Comment: Refer to [this tutorial](https://www.javatpoint.com/android-popup-menu-example).

Comment: You can find the log by following the instruction here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19784877/how-to-find-the-logs-on-android-studio

Comment: Abhi, I did the entire tutorial redoing all the code, and I got the same result. It continues to crash...

Comment: Also I added the link to the log at the bottom

Comment: you should paste the log here. I can't seem to open that link.

Comment: ok, but it's very long

Comment: it says it is 550 thousand characters

Comment: please have your logcat open when you touch your `help` button, your log will display the exception - copy/paste that

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 0):

**myButton** is null here.
 you are missing this

```
myButton = (Button)customView.findViewById(R.id.myButtonId);
```