# studio64.exe doesnt not start even after setting environments

Tags: android, android-studio, java-11, windows64

After installing last version of android studio I can't open the IDE any more every time I try to click on EXE file nothing happens.

I have set `JDK_HOME` and `JAVA_HOME` in Windows environment and I have tried to do clean install but still nothing happens when I try to run the program.

---

**UPDATE**

I managed to get this error log from this path
C:\Users"name"\AppData\Local\Google\AndroidStudio2020.3\log

```
2021-09-02 14:11:27,275 [      0]   INFO -        #com.intellij.idea.Main - ------------------------------------------------------ IDE STARTED ------------------------------------------------------ 
2021-09-02 14:11:27,316 [     41]   INFO -        #com.intellij.idea.Main - IDE: Android Studio (build #AI-203.7717.56.2031.7583922, 26 Jul 2021 21:59) 
2021-09-02 14:11:27,318 [     43]   INFO -        #com.intellij.idea.Main - OS: Windows 10 (10.0, amd64) 
2021-09-02 14:11:27,328 [     53]   INFO -        #com.intellij.idea.Main - JRE: 11.0.10+0-b96-7249189 (Oracle Corporation) 
2021-09-02 14:11:27,329 [     54]   INFO -        #com.intellij.idea.Main - JVM: 11.0.10+0-b96-7249189 (OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM) 
2021-09-02 14:11:27,332 [     57]   INFO -        #com.intellij.idea.Main - JVM Args: exit -Xms256m -Xmx1280m -XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=512m -XX:+UseG1GC -XX:SoftRefLRUPolicyMSPerMB=50 -XX:CICompilerCount=2 -Dsun.io.useCanonCaches=false -Djdk.http.auth.tunneling.disabledSchemes="" -Djdk.attach.allowAttachSelf=true -Djdk.module.illegalAccess.silent=true -Dkotlinx.coroutines.debug=off -Djna.nosys=true -Djna.boot.library.path= -Didea.vendor.name=Google -Djb.vmOptionsFile=C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\bin\studio64.exe.vmoptions -Djava.library.path=C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\\bin;C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\\bin\server -Didea.platform.prefix=AndroidStudio -Didea.jre.check=true -Dide.native.launcher=true -Didea.vendor.name=Google -Didea.paths.selector=AndroidStudio2020.3 -XX:ErrorFile=C:\Users\hossam hassan\java_error_in_studio64_%p.log -XX:HeapDumpPath=C:\Users\hossam hassan\java_error_in_studio64.hprof 
2021-09-02 14:11:27,333 [     58]   INFO -        #com.intellij.idea.Main - library path: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\\bin;C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\\bin\server 
2021-09-02 14:11:27,333 [     58]   INFO -        #com.intellij.idea.Main - boot library path: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\bin 
2021-09-02 14:11:27,360 [     85]   INFO -        #com.intellij.idea.Main - locale=en_US JNU=Cp1256 file.encoding=Cp1256
  idea.config.path=C:\Users\hossam hassan\AppData\Roaming\Google\AndroidStudio2020.3
  idea.system.path=C:\Users\hossam hassan\AppData\Local\Google\AndroidStudio2020.3
  idea.plugins.path=C:\Users\hossam hassan\AppData\Roaming\Google\AndroidStudio2020.3\plugins
  idea.log.path=C:\Users\hossam hassan\AppData\Local\Google\AndroidStudio2020.3\log 
2021-09-02 14:11:27,453 [    178]   INFO -        #com.intellij.idea.Main - JNA library (64-bit) loaded in 92 ms 
2021-09-02 14:11:27,476 [    201]   INFO - penapi.util.io.win32.IdeaWin32 - Native filesystem for Windows is operational 
2021-09-02 14:11:27,477 [    202]   INFO -                         STDERR -  
2021-09-02 14:11:27,478 [    203]   INFO -                         STDERR - Start Failed 
2021-09-02 14:11:27,478 [    203]   INFO -                         STDERR - Internal error. Please refer to https://code.google.com/p/android/issues 
2021-09-02 14:11:27,478 [    203]   INFO -                         STDERR -  
2021-09-02 14:11:27,478 [    203]   INFO -                         STDERR - com.intellij.ide.plugins.StartupAbortedException: UI initialization failed 
2021-09-02 14:11:27,478 [    203]   INFO -                         STDERR -     at com.intellij.idea.StartupUtil.lambda$prepareApp$3(StartupUtil.java:194) 
2021-09-02 14:11:27,478 [    203]   INFO -                         STDERR -     at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniExceptionally(CompletableFuture.java:986) 
2021-09-02 14:11:27,478 [    203]   INFO -                         STDERR -     at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniExceptionally.tryFire(CompletableFuture.java:970) 
2021-09-02 14:11:27,478 [    203]   INFO -                         STDERR -     at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.postComplete(CompletableFuture.java:506) 
2021-09-02 14:11:27,478 [    203]   INFO -                         STDERR -     at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.completeExceptionally(CompletableFuture.java:2088) 
2021-09-02 14:11:27,479 [    204]   INFO -                         STDERR -     at com.intellij.idea.StartupUtil.lambda$scheduleInitUi$9(StartupUtil.java:375) 
2021-09-02 14:11:27,479 [    204]   INFO -                         STDERR -     at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128) 
2021-09-02 14:11:27,479 [    204]   INFO -                         STDERR -     at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628) 
2021-09-02 14:11:27,479 [    204]   INFO -                         STDERR -     at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$PrivilegedThreadFactory$1$1.run(Executors.java:668) 
2021-09-02 14:11:27,479 [    204]   INFO -                         STDERR -     at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$PrivilegedThreadFactory$1$1.run(Executors.java:665) 
2021-09-02 14:11:27,479 [    204]   INFO -                         STDERR -     at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) 
2021-09-02 14:11:27,479 [    204]   INFO -                         STDERR -     at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$PrivilegedThreadFactory$1.run(Executors.java:665) 
2021-09-02 14:11:27,479 [    204]   INFO -                         STDERR -     at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834) 
2021-09-02 14:11:27,479 [    204]   INFO -                         STDERR - Caused by: java.util.concurrent.CompletionException: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\bin\awt.dll: %1 is not a valid Win32 application 
2021-09-02 14:11:27,479 [    204]   INFO -                         STDERR -     at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.encodeThrowable(CompletableFuture.java:331) 
2021-09-02 14:11:27,479 [    204]   INFO -                         STDERR -     at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.completeThrowable(CompletableFuture.java:346) 
2021-09-02 14:11:27,479 [    204]   INFO -                         STDERR -     at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$BiRelay.tryFire(CompletableFuture.java:1423) 
2021-09-02 14:11:27,479 [    204]   INFO -                         STDERR -     ... 10 more 
2021-09-02 14:11:27,479 [    204]   INFO -                         STDERR - Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\bin\awt.dll: %1 is not a valid Win32 application 
2021-09-02 14:11:27,480 [    205]   INFO -                         STDERR -     at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load0(Native Method) 
2021-09-02 14:11:27,480 [    205]   INFO -                         STDERR -     at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(ClassLoader.java:2442) 
2021-09-02 14:11:27,480 [    205]   INFO -                         STDERR -     at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:2498) 
2021-09-02 14:11:27,480 [    205]   INFO -                         STDERR -     at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(ClassLoader.java:2694) 
2021-09-02 14:11:27,480 [    205]   INFO -                         STDERR -     at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:2648) 
2021-09-02 14:11:27,480 [    205]   INFO -                         STDERR -     at java.base/java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:830) 
2021-09-02 14:11:27,480 [    205]   INFO -                         STDERR -     at java.base/java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1873) 
2021-09-02 14:11:27,480 [    205]   INFO -                         STDERR -     at java.desktop/java.awt.Toolkit$3.run(Toolkit.java:1395) 
2021-09-02 14:11:27,480 [    205]   INFO -                         STDERR -     at java.desktop/java.awt.Toolkit$3.run(Toolkit.java:1393) 
2021-09-02 14:11:27,480 [    205]   INFO -                         STDERR -     at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) 
2021-09-02 14:11:27,480 [    205]   INFO -                         STDERR -     at java.desktop/java.awt.Toolkit.loadLibraries(Toolkit.java:1392) 
2021-09-02 14:11:27,480 [    205]   INFO -                         STDERR -     at java.desktop/java.awt.Toolkit.<clinit>(Toolkit.java:1430) 
2021-09-02 14:11:27,480 [    205]   INFO -                         STDERR -     at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(EventQueue.java:1318) 
2021-09-02 14:11:27,480 [    205]   INFO -                         STDERR -     at com.intellij.idea.StartupUtil.lambda$scheduleInitUi$9(StartupUtil.java:326) 
2021-09-02 14:11:27,480 [    205]   INFO -                         STDERR -     ... 7 more 
2021-09-02 14:11:27,480 [    205]   INFO -                         STDERR -  
2021-09-02 14:11:27,481 [    206]   INFO -                         STDERR - ----- 
2021-09-02 14:11:27,481 [    206]   INFO -                         STDERR - Your JRE: 11.0.10+0-b96-7249189 amd64 (Oracle Corporation) 
2021-09-02 14:11:27,481 [    206]   INFO -                         STDERR - C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre 
2021-09-02 14:11:27,506 [    231]   INFO -                         STDERR -  
2021-09-02 14:11:27,507 [    232]   INFO -                         STDERR - Also, a UI exception occurred on an attempt to show the above message 
2021-09-02 14:11:27,507 [    232]   INFO -                         STDERR - java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class java.awt.Toolkit 
2021-09-02 14:11:27,508 [    233]   INFO -                         STDERR -     at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.<clinit>(Component.java:626) 
2021-09-02 14:11:27,508 [    233]   INFO -                         STDERR -     at com.intellij.idea.Main.showMessage(Main.java:317) 
2021-09-02 14:11:27,508 [    233]   INFO -                         STDERR -     at com.intellij.idea.Main.showMessage(Main.java:270) 
2021-09-02 14:11:27,509 [    234]   INFO -                         STDERR -     at com.intellij.ide.plugins.StartupAbortedException.logAndExit(StartupAbortedException.java:86) 
2021-09-02 14:11:27,509 [    234]   INFO -                         STDERR -     at com.intellij.ide.plugins.StartupAbortedException.processException(StartupAbortedException.java:34) 
2021-09-02 14:11:27,509 [    234]   INFO -                         STDERR -     at com.intellij.idea.StartupUtil.lambda$prepareApp$3(StartupUtil.java:194) 
2021-09-02 14:11:27,509 [    234]   INFO -                         STDERR -     at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniExceptionally(CompletableFuture.java:986) 
2021-09-02 14:11:27,509 [    234]   INFO -                         STDERR -     at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniExceptionally.tryFire(CompletableFuture.java:970) 
2021-09-02 14:11:27,510 [    235]   INFO -                         STDERR -     at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.postComplete(CompletableFuture.java:506) 
2021-09-02 14:11:27,511 [    236]   INFO -                         STDERR -     at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.completeExceptionally(CompletableFuture.java:2088) 
2021-09-02 14:11:27,511 [    236]   INFO -                         STDERR -     at com.intellij.idea.StartupUtil.lambda$scheduleInitUi$9(StartupUtil.java:375) 
2021-09-02 14:11:27,511 [    236]   INFO -                         STDERR -     at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128) 
2021-09-02 14:11:27,511 [    236]   INFO -                         STDERR -     at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628) 
2021-09-02 14:11:27,512 [    237]   INFO -                         STDERR -     at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$PrivilegedThreadFactory$1$1.run(Executors.java:668) 
2021-09-02 14:11:27,512 [    237]   INFO -                         STDERR -     at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$PrivilegedThreadFactory$1$1.run(Executors.java:665) 
2021-09-02 14:11:27,512 [    237]   INFO -                         STDERR -     at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) 
2021-09-02 14:11:27,512 [    237]   INFO -                         STDERR -     at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$PrivilegedThreadFactory$1.run(Executors.java:665) 
2021-09-02 14:11:27,513 [    238]   INFO -                         STDERR -     at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834) 
2021-09-02 14:11:27,514 [    239]   INFO -        #com.intellij.idea.Main - ------------------------------------------------------ IDE SHUTDOWN ------------------------------------------------------ 
2021-09-02 14:11:27,802 [    527]   INFO - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - Plugin PluginDescriptor(name=Groovy, id=org.intellij.groovy, path=C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\plugins\Groovy, version=203.7717.56.2031.7583922) misses optional descriptor duplicates-groovy.xml 
2021-09-02 14:11:27,803 [    528]   INFO - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - Plugin PluginDescriptor(name=Groovy, id=org.intellij.groovy, path=C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\plugins\Groovy, version=203.7717.56.2031.7583922) misses optional descriptor duplicates-detection-groovy.xml 
2021-09-02 14:11:27,865 [    590]   INFO - org.jetbrains.io.BuiltInServer - web server stopped
```

Comment: is there any log file that i can check to see what is the problem when i click on exe file?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19784877/how-to-find-the-logs-on-android-studio

Comment: Can you redownload and try installing studio again

Comment: Maybe you downloaded 64bit version of android studio and your system is 32 bit

Comment: i have tried reinstall more than once and i do have system 64

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue, found answer here https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-259821 by installing VC Redist https://aka.ms/vs/16/release/vc_redist.x64.exe

Comment: This worked, wow just wow